# Continuous function: prove that limit in $0$ implies function is $0$ for a point in a certain interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

$f: (\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous  and

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{3})+f(x+\frac{2}{3})}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Prove that $t \in (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})$ exists, such that $f(t) = 0$.

Comment: Condition given implies $f(\frac{1}{3})+f(\frac{2}{3})=0$. So either (1) $f(\frac{1}{3})=f(\frac{2}{3})=0$ or (2) $f(\frac{1}{3})-f(\frac{2}{3})\ne0$. In case (2) the intermediate value theorem tells us there is a zero between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By continuity of $f$, the limit can only exists if $f(\frac{1}{3}) + f(\frac{2}{3}) = 0$ (it's a necessary but not sufficient condition, but that doesn't matter here)

So, either $f(\frac{1}{3}) = f(\frac{2}{3}) = 0$ , and you have your $t$

Either $f(\frac{1}{3}) < 0 < f(\frac{2}{3}) $ (or the opposite)

Then you can use the intermediate value theorem to have your $t$

Comment: IVT would also work.

Comment: My bad, I meant IVT... I always mistake the two names in englicsh (not my usual language)

Comment: English is my usual language and I still mix up completeness and compactness so we're all in the same boat when it comes to mixing up terminology :)

Comment: May you explain why limit exists only when sum of those functions is $0$?

Comment: @BagofChips: Clearly since $f$ is continuous we have $$f(1/3) + f(2/3) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x + 1/3) + f(x + 2/3) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x + 1/3) + f(x + 2/3)}{x^{2}}\cdot x^{2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 0 = 0$$